# How to copy a function or class to another file?

Tags: java, eclipse

i am developing a plug-in in which i search where a particular method say 'aaa'is called. Then i find out the function in which this particular method 'aaa'is called.I want to copy this particular method or the class in which aaa is called to another file.How can i do that?Help

Comment: If Boris' answer (or a simple copy/paste) is not doing what you want, then you need to explain your question a little more.

Comment: Why? Why do you want to duplicate code? This is poor practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at the [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes`](http://kickjava.com/src/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.index.htm) package, especially at the [**`CopyCompilationUnitChange`**](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/changes/CopyCompilationUnitChange.java.htm) class.

It does copy a "[compilation unit](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/ICompilationUnit.java.htm)", which includes a class or method.

```
getCu().copy(getDestinationPackage(), null, getNewName(), true, pm);
```

It uses the copy function of [`org.eclipse.jdt.core.ISourceManipulation`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/ISourceManipulation.java.htm)

Comment: On reading this, I guess this is what the OP most likely wanted. I'll leave my answer up in any case...

Answer (score 1):

If you mean adding a method to an existing class at runtime, your best bet is to use something like [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/).

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass source = pool.get("MySourceClass");
CtMethod sourceMethod = source.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod");
CtClass dest = pool.get("MyDestClass");
dest.addMethod(sourceMethod);
dest.writeFile();
```

This will require some work to get right, but this should be the general idea. Note that I haven't done any exception handling etc. here. You will need to read, at minimum, the [Javassist tutorial](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial.html) and possibly, if you need to do something really arcane, the relevant bits of the [JVM spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html).

Answer (score 0):

select the method name

right click

Refactoring

Move

choose destination class and click OK

Comment: not like that.i mean using methods.its a plug in where i want to copy some specific methods to some other place